# Unable to invoke method setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled for ConnectionFactory in Rabbitmq

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am trying to setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled for my connection factory. However, I get a compile error unable to recognize the method setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled for factory object.

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true); // unable to recognize the
//method setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled.
```

pom dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
    <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this and give some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the dependency version to 3.5.1:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
<artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
<version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This worked.